# Trek 6000 for a beginner

Tags: mountain-bike

I own a local brand and am hoping to shift to a new bike. I have an option to buy a Trek 6000 D. I know it is an expensive bike. I am looking to use the bike every day for about 5-30 kms. A few offroad days hopefully, but thats about it.

Wondering if this is a good idea? Your suggestions please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trek makes good, reliable bikes across their price range.  I have 25 of 'em in our patrol-bike "fleet" at present.
The 6000 is well-reviewed, but it is designed and delivered as an off-road machine.  It will be less than optimum when ridden on pavement.
If you were going to spend most of your time riding on pavement, then a simple change of tires would be of considerable benefit.
Not that you can't ride a mountain bike on the road, thousands do so all the time.  It's just that those knobby tires will squirm and wear rapidly, and the riding position is not the best for long stretches on the road.

Answer (score 1):

M. Werner explained the purpose of that model pretty well.

If you are worried about buying "too expensive bike", do not be so. If you can afford something, you should not be ashamed of using professional equipment for your own activities. you will enjoy smoother shifting and rides.

With expensive bikes comes another problem - you can not leave it outside, even if it is locked to something.

Comment: @Alec By the way I do leave my bike parked outside, every week day in the day time (I use it for commuting); and it cost about the same as the one you're thinking of. It's a public street, and I've tried to use a good lock. "Your mileage may vary", I guess.